# TFS Loses History when Merging

Tags: version-control, tfs

Both Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2005 and 2008 lose history (check-ins + comments) on files when they branched and merged back. So e.g. if changes in a branch are made then merged back to the root branch, none of the changes made in the branch are visible in the root branch. The only thing visible in the history states that a merge occurred.

Does anyone know if there is an option which can be set to retain the history, or a different way to do the merge which keeps the history?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- You are correct that TFS does not track history by default when merging.  There is a [powertool](http://web.archive.org/web/20080321032248/http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718351.aspx), however, that allows you to do so (see **History Command** under **TFS Power Tool Commands**).
- See [this comment](http://blog.decaresystems.ie/2007/04/02/limitations-of-branching-and-merging-with-tfs/#comment-207) for more details:

> “If TFS would only maintain the history of branched files, rather than starting them from scratch every time a branch is done, then a similar safe merge would be possible between branches”
>
> You can install the Power Tools and then use the /followbranches flag to retrieve the history information: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718351.aspx
>
> History Command
> Use the history command to display the revision history for one or more files and folders. The /followbranches option returns the history of the file branch's ancestors.
>
> There is also a codeplex project to enable the option in the GUI:
> http://www.codeplex.com/TFSBranchHistory

Comment: Thanks. The branched history plugin is Awsome (but a little slow).

Comment: Well that's Microsoft's fault...I fixed the links, using an archive from the Wayback Machine for the Microsoft one.  Apparently releasing a new TFS version means they can just obliterate all the older online documentation `:/`

Answer (score 2):

TFS Branched History plugin for VS2010 is now available from Microsoft Gallery:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7d4f37b6-f9a4-44c6-b0a0-994956538a44
This plugin is just query history from different branches and make union of the records.

Answer (score 1):

The TFS Branched History plugin from Microsoft Gallery only works with VS2010.

For those using Visual Studio 2008, [here is a plugin](http://tfsbranchhistory.codeplex.com/) that provides the same functionality.

After you install it, open up VS2008 and  go to the TFS Source Control window.

- Right-click on an item and you will see a new option in the context menu called "Branched History".
- Click on this to get the history of the item in all previous TFS branches. Give it a few seconds if you're on a slow machine.

In the "Branched History" window you can also View or Compare file versions just as you can in the regular "History" window.

Comment: It can't be done without this plugin in VS2008. I'm not sure about later versions of VS. But you can of course query the TFS database directly via T-SQL....